# Alfresco audit: show user's OS

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, audit-trail

I want Alfresco's audit to show, for each logged action, what was the operating system of the user.

For instance, if a user delete a document using Firefox on Ubuntu Linux 16.10, the audit line would have the information `Ubuntu Linux 16.10`. Showing the browser's user agent name would be enough, as it usually (always?) contains the OS name.

I need the information for all users even if they access Alfresco via Alfresco Share. This is trickier because the web browser's UA ([User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP)) information does not make it past Alfresco Share:

```
Web browser -------------> Alfresco Share -------------------> Alfresco repository
              UA present                    UA lost already
```

While other pieces of information can be enabled, I haven't found how to make the OS show up, and [the documentation](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/audit-custom-audit-config.html) does not mention that. Is it doable? Maybe with custom development?

Comment: Isn't it possible to have some information via the access-logs and do some correlation ?

Comment: @Akah: If you have details that would make a great answer :-)